# CoffeeScript: Using instanceof vs Class.constructor.name

Tags: coffeescript

If I have a class:

```
class Haha
  constructor: (@lolAmount = 1) ->
    alert @lolAmount
```

And I want to check if an object is of the right class, Is it always safe to use `constructor.name`:

```
haha = new Haha()
unless haha.constructor.name is 'Haha'
  throw Error 'Wrong type'
```

or is it better to use `instanceof`:

```
haha = new Haha()
unless haha instanceof Haha
  throw Error 'Wrong type'
```

One argument I have for `instanceof` is when using `extends`:

```
class BigHaha extends Haha

bigHaha = new BigHaha
console.log bigHaha instanceof Haha #true
```

but how safe is it, being a JavaScript operator - I feel like I should be sceptical about it.

On the other hand, with `constructor.name` it is very clear what is happening. Is it guaranteed that `constructor.name` will be set on all objects?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) is also straight JavaScript:

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.

So when you say `o.constructor`, you're really doing straight JavaScript, the name `constructor` for the CoffeeScript object initialization function is a separate matter.

So now you have a choice between using JavaScript's `constructor` property or JavaScript's `instanceof` operator. The `constructor` just tells you what "class" was used to create the object, [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) on the other hand:

> [...] tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the `prototype` property of a constructor.

So `instanceof` is the right choice if you want to allow for subclassing.

Comment: Great thanks! Just to confirm though, the `name` property on the constructor is CoffeeScript yes? And is reliable for classes where I don't care about sub/superclasses?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal: The [`name` comes from JavaScript's `Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) and is non-standard so it may or may not work. Use `instanceof` or compare the `constructor` function directly. But really, just use `instanceof`.

Comment: I recall a discussion in the coffeescript issues about the `constructor.name` property being mangled by closure/uglifyjs. Another good thing to know is that `instanceof` is only really safe to use for your own objects, and not the built-in types. But I agree, for this use, `instanceof` is the better choice. *Edit:* [here is a similar discussion](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/issues/290).

Comment: @LinusGThiel: I could see running into `name` problems in all sorts of ways, especially if you're mixing JS and CS (`M = Backbone.Model.extend({})`, for example, is anonymous). And yes, all bets are off with native types.

Comment: I've been using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for native type-checking - would you consider `instanceof` for my own classes and `_.isWhatever` for native objects to be fairly robust?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal: Yes, that should be pretty reliable.

Comment: anyway to support IE? I'm getting "this.constructor.name is null or not an object"

Comment: @Rob: Use `instanceof`? That's probably what you want anyway. See the discussion of `.name` in the rest of the comments.