# Difference between instanceof and constructor property

Tags: javascript

Is `a instanceof b` exactly equivalent to `a.constructor === b`? If not, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Hope it is helping

http://stackoverflow.com/q/18055980/1989472

Comment: @Rajasekhar that couldn't be more misleading, it doesn't focus on the semantics of `.constructor` vs `instanceof`.. but rather confusions around strings and objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript: Using instanceof vs Class.constructor.name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690894/coffeescript-using-instanceof-vs-class-constructor-name)

Comment: Check this example: `[] instanceof Object` but `[].constructor != Object`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> "Is a instanceof b exactly equivalent to a.constructor === b?

**No.**

> "If not, what's the difference between the two?"

`instanceof` also checks for "inherited" constructors.

For more information, see the spec.  ([here](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.6) and [here](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.3))

---

Code example:

```js
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}
const c = new Child()

c instanceof Child // true
c instanceof Parent // true (Inherited)

c.constructor === Child // true
c.constructor === Parent // false
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a code example that highlights the difference? Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

[SLaks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172929/4284627) is correct, but I would like to add that `.constructor` works on primitive types and `instanceof` doesn't:

```
"Hello World".constructor == String;    //true
"Hello World" instanceof String;    //false
```

The reason why the second condition is false is because `"Hello World"` is a primitive string and not an object so it isn't an instance of anything. In the first condition, on the other hand, when applying a method (such as `constructor`) to a primitive type, it gets converted to an object. So first `"Hello World"` gets converted to `new String("Hello World")` and then returns `new String("Hello World").constructor` which is `String`. This works the same way for numbers and booleans.

You can also use `typeof` on primitive types, but that won't work on objects:

```
typeof "Hello World";    //"string"
typeof new String("Hello World");    //"object"
```

So if you're dealing with strings, numbers or booleans and you don't need to worry about inheritance, you should use:

- `.constructor` if you want to check if the variable is a string, number or boolean and it doesn't matter if it's a primitive type or an object.

  There are also other ways of doing this like `typeof foo.valueOf()` or `(foo instanceof String || typeof foo == "string")`, but `.constructor` is the shortest. However, the longer ways can be useful if for some reason you have classes that inherit `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` and you also want to check for inherited types.
- `instanceof` if you want to check if the variable is a `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` object and not a primitive type.
- `typeof` if you want to check if the type of the variable is a primitive type and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are dealing with objects, the constructor property can be overwritten (if you write `ObjectName.prototype`), so it’s generally **better to** use the `instanceof` method to check the type of an object.

Or you can specify the constructor inside the prototype declaration:

```
ObjectName.prototype = {
  constructor: ObjectName,
  someOtherProp: ''
}
```