# why every javascript object has constructor property?

Tags: javascript

Just trying to understand why every JavaScript object has a constructor property.

Is there any use of constructor property because object is already created?

```
var MyFunc = function (name){this.name=name}

var instance = new MyFunc("myclass");
```

now instance has a constructor property which has reference to MyFunc itself. What is use of having constructor property on instance?

Answer (score 1):

It is (much) more complicated than that : no object, in, JS has a `constructor` property by default, but their **prototype** (if the object has a prototype) have one.

Also, be careful : the `constructor` references a function, but this prototype property is not read-only, so one can easily change the property, therefore do not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question ?

```
var dog1= {"a":1}

function Dog ()
{

}


dog2= new Dog();

console.log(dog1.constructor) //function Object() { [native code]...
console.log(dog2.constructor) //function Dog()...
```

Sometimes you need to know how object was created. ( not to mention that prototype is a constructor property)

Comment: We can use instanceof?

Comment: @GauravSingla http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172902/difference-between-instanceof-and-constructor-property

Comment: I understood the difference. Still why there is need of constructor property. Do we really need to compare constructors?

Comment: @GauravSingla If you wanted to modify `Dog.prototype`, but you only had access to the `dog2` instance, you could access `Dog.prototype` with `dog2.constructor.prototype`.