# instanceof operator Vs obj.constructor

Tags: javascript

I want to know if is there any difference between these two methods of checking whether an object is an instance of a class/constructor. I searched about it and found these two ways.

```
obj instanceof SomeConstructor

obj.constructor === SomeConstructor
```

So my questions are:
Is there any difference between the two?

Which one is a better practice?

Also, Is there any other way better than these two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between instanceof and constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172902/difference-between-instanceof-and-constructor-property)

Comment: An object can be an *instanceOf* many constructors. It can only return one *constructor* property value, which may not point to any of the objects for which *instanceOf* returns true.

Comment: @Dane sir that question answers only one of my 3 queries. So I think it shouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: @RohitAgrawal—in a way it answers the second, since they not directly comparable you can't really evaluate "better" without some criteria to make an evaluation. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Found this on web,

**instanceof**

The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

**constructor**

Returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name.

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: And the other 2 questions? ;-) Also, the second definition is not necessarily correct. An object's inherited *constructor* property can be set to any value.

Answer (score 0):

As per the explanation of @Nisal Edu there, the `instanceof` is carrying prototype exists into the object chain else return false. `obj.constructor === Object` is necessary value for every object this return true.

*It's mean*

```
obj.constructor === Object // always return true
obj instanceof Object //return false if prototype is nowhere in object's prototype chain
```

Comment: As said by @RobG,  An object's inherited constructor property can be set to any value. Therefore, `obj.constructor === Object` is not always true

Comment: but if `obj` is an `Object` then this statement is always true in my opinion.

Comment: `Object` can be any constructor. It was for example.

Comment: I think I explain it only for the prototype.